# JSON and struct composition in Go

Tags: json, go, struct, marshalling, encode

I have hierarchical structure similar to this `Network -> Serie -> Season -> Episodes`. This is a simplified version my real hierarchy is 7 levels deep.

I need to decode/encode these objects with the following JSON:

```
Network:
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Fox'
}

Series:
{
   id: 2,
   name: 'The Simpsons',
   network: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Fox'
   }
}

Season:
{
   id: 3,
   name: 'Season 3',
   network: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Fox'

   },
   series: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'The Simpsons'
   }
}

Episode:
{
   id: 4,
   name: 'Pilot',
   network: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Fox'
   },
   series: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'The Simpsons'
   },
   season: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Season 3'
   }
}
```

I tried composing my objects like these:

```
type Base struct {
  ID   string `json:"id"`
  Name string `json:"name"`
}

type Network struct {
  Base
}

type Series struct {
  Network // Flatten out all Network properties (ID + Name)
  Network Base `json:"network"`
}

type Season struct {
  Series  // Flatten out all Series properties (ID + Name + Network)
  Series Base `json:"series"`
}

type Episode struct {
  Season  // Flatten out all Season properties (ID + Name + Network + Series)
  Season Season `json:"season"`
}
```

Of course it doesn't work due `"duplicate field error"`. In addition the JSON result would be deeply nested.
In classic OOP this is fairly easy using normal inheritance, in prototype languages it's also doable (Object.create/Mixins)

Is there an elegant way of do this with golang? I would prefer to keep code DRY.

Answer (score 3):

Why not rename the propriety? But keep the json tags, and go will marshal/unmarshal based on that tag

```
type Base struct {
    ID   string `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type Network struct {
    Base
}

type Series struct {
    Network          // Flatten out all Network properties (ID + Name)
    NetworkBase Base `json:"network"`
}

type Season struct {
    Series          // Flatten out all Series properties (ID + Name + Network)
    SeriesBase Base `json:"series"`
}

type Episode struct {
    Season              // Flatten out all Season properties (ID + Name + Network + Series)
    SeasonBase Base `json:"season"`
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible but to be honest the way you need to build the objects and to reference *Base looks fill of clutter.
For instance compare golang version (https://play.golang.org/p/4Mwx3dxck_) vs an inheritance approach in Groovy (https://cafe-huitre.appspot.com/script/5715999101812736)

Comment: Well go doesn't support inheritance, it supports composition and embedding.  https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding